# Update the same question or make another question, which is recommended?

Tags: discussion, questions

I recently had a [question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/273590/abstraction-in-algorithms?noredirect=1#comment559958_273590), after I posted it, someone answered me. based on it's answer another question aroused.

Then I don't know whether it's better to ask it in the same question or make a new question for it?
I thought if I continue it there, then I have a more complete question, however a user suggested me to make a new post.

In general which is recommended and when I should make another question and when update the same question?

Comment: askers better avoid [“chameleon questions”](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478/165773), as these tend to frustrate answerers

Comment: @gnat thanks, then a new question? anyway, I don't think the answer I referred in my update, without addressing the ambiguity aroused is complete

Answer (score 2):

**Do not edit your question into another one.**

It makes any existing answers useless and any votes meaningless.

Ask a new question but link back to your original one to show why you are asking this one.